# JavaScript function not returning correct data

Tags: javascript

I have 3 datasets which are an array of objects and I want to change the `text` property value.

Some datasets have a recursive structure. It means it has a `children` property which is an array of object with the same structure.

I made a function which changes text value based on the `id`. But facing a problem in the iteration of the `2nd` or `3rd` dataset. I'm using the `map` method for iteration, check if the `item` has a `children` property and calling the same method again.

**Why on `2nd` or `3rd` dataset, the function is returning children property value?**

```
// Dataset 1
const data = [{
    id: '1',
    pid: null,
    children: null,
    text: ''
}];

// Dataset 2
const data2 = [{
    id: '1',
    pid: null,
    text: '',
    children: [{
        id: '1.1',
        pid: '1',
        children: null,
        text: ''
    }],
}];

// Dataset 3
const data3 = [{
    id: '1',
    pid: null,
    text: '',
    children: [{
            id: '1.1',
            pid: '1',
            children: null,
            text: ''
        },
        {
            id: '1.2',
            pid: '1',
            children: null,
            text: ''
        }
    ],

}];

/**
 * @param {string} iD
 * @param {string} text
 * @param {Array.<Object>} data
 * @returns {Array.<Object>}
 */
const changeText = (iD, text, data) => {
    const newArr = data.map(item => {
        if (item.id === iD) {
            // Construct new array of object with updated values
            return {
                ...item,
                text
            };
        } else {
            if (item.children !== null && item.children.length > 0) {
                return changeText(iD, text, item.children)
            }
            // Wrong id return old data
            return item;
        }

    });
    return newArr;
};

// Test for 1st Dataset
console.log('--Dataset 1---');
console.log(changeText('1', 'Foo', data)); // Passed
console.log('--Dataset 1---');
console.log(changeText('1.1', 'Foo', data)); // Passed

// Test for 2nd Dataset
console.log('--Dataset 2---');
console.log(changeText('1.1', 'Foo', data2)); // Value is changed but children array is return

// Test for 3rd Dataset
console.log('--Dataset 3---');
console.log(changeText('1.2', 'Foo', data3)); // Value is changed but children array is return
```

Comment: the problem is in the changeText function, where you return the `changeText(iD, text, item.children)`. Instead, you should assign that result to item.children, then let it return the full item with the updated children: ```if (item.children !== null && item.children.length > 0) {
    item.children = changeText(iD, text, item.children)
}
return item;```

Comment: Remember that for now Edge doesn't support the spread syntax on object literals. You can circumvent this by doing: `item.text = text; return item;`.

Comment: @Mouser thanks point to be noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set item.children as the result of the recursive call of changeText and return the item itself (after the change).

If you don't want to alter item.children value, you should return a new object with updated children property (return { children: changeText(..), ... }) instead of the "original" item.

```js
// Dataset 1
const data = [{
    id: '1',
    pid: null,
    children: null,
    text: ''
}];

// Dataset 2
const data2 = [{
    id: '1',
    pid: null,
    text: '',
    children: [{
        id: '1.1',
        pid: '1',
        children: null,
        text: ''
    }],
}];

// Dataset 3
const data3 = [{
    id: '1',
    pid: null,
    text: '',
    children: [{
        id: '1.1',
        pid: '1',
        children: null,
        text: ''
    },
        {
            id: '1.2',
            pid: '1',
            children: null,
            text: ''
        }
    ],

}];

/**
 * @param {string} iD
 * @param {string} text
 * @param {Array.<Object>} data
 * @returns {Array.<Object>}
 */
const changeText = (iD, text, data) => {
    const newArr = data.map(item => {
        if (item.id === iD) {
            // Construct new array of object with updated values
            return {
                ...item,
                text
            };
        } else {
            if (item.children !== null && item.children.length > 0) {
                item.children = changeText(iD, text, item.children);
                return item;
            }
            // Wrong id return old data
            return item;
        }

    });
    return newArr;
};

// Test for 1st Dataset
let resultArray = [];
console.log('--Dataset 1---');
console.log(changeText('1', 'Foo', data)); // Passed
console.log('--Dataset 1---');
console.log(changeText('1.1', 'Foo', data)); // Passed

// Test for 2nd Dataset
console.log('--Dataset 2---');
console.log(changeText('1.1', 'Foo', data2)); // Value is changed but subpart return

// Test for 3rd Dataset
console.log('--Dataset 3---');
console.log(changeText('1.2', 'Foo', data3)); // Value is changed but subpart return
```

Comment: What do you mean by If you don't want to alter the item.children value. Could you elaborate? It means don't want to mutate children property.

Comment: Yeah I did mean to "don't want to mutate children property". In this case use:
                return {
                    id: item.id,
                    pid: item.pid,
                    children: changeText(iD, text, item.children),
                    text: item.text
                };